# ASP.NET MVC editor template containing submit form, values are null when reaching controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a parent Endowment that has many Criterion in a collection called Criteria.  I am building an edit form where I want to edit the parent attributes as well as add/remove a criterion.

Endowment.cs, Criterion.cs and EndowmentEditViewModel.cs

```
public class Endowmment {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Criterion> Criteria {get; set;}
}

public class Criterion {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int EndowmentID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string SortOrder {get; set;}
}

public class EndowmentEditViewModel {
    public Endowment Endowment {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

In the Endowment Edit view, I have referenced an editor template for the criterion collection called criteria, since there are many for one endowment.  The editor template is outside of the form for the Endowment.

Views/Endowment/Edit.cshtml

```
@model EndowmentEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Endowment")
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Endowment.ID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Endowment.Description)
    <input type="submit" value="Save endowment" />
}

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Endowment.Criteria)
```

In the Criterion editortemplate, I want to be able to save or delete a Criterion row.

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Criterion.cshtml

```
@model Criterion

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Criterion"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SortOrder)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Criterion", new { @id = Model.ID }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("ID", Model.ID)
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

The delete action works fine, however, when I click "Save", the values are posted in the browser request, but the Edit action on the Criterion controller receives them as null values.

Controllers/CriterionController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Criterion model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveCriterion(model);
        // insert happy message
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Criterion {0} was saved", model.Description);
    }
    else
    {
        // there is something wrong with the data values
        // inesrt fail message
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Endowment", new { id = model.EndowmentID });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work:

In my view, Views/Endowment/Edit.cshtml

```
@*@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Endowment.Criteria)*@
@foreach (var criterion in Model.Endowment.Criteria)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => criterion)
}
....
```

In the controller /Controllers/CriterionController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "criterion")] Criterion model)
{
    ...
```

No change in the editor template.

Strange.  I thought `foreach` was boo-hooed in a view, but it worked for this particular purpose.  Well, I guess any parent/child in the same view is boo-hooed too, but it works for me.  If there is a better way, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly better way.  MVC will enumerate model objects for you and display your editor template once for each item in a list.  For example, this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => criterion) //Assumes criterion is is a list or collection
```

Does the same thing as this:

```
@foreach (var criterion in Model.Endowment.Criteria)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => criterion)
}
```